# Where did this shield come from in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

So, in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Stark gives Steve Rogers his shield back,

but it's

> destroyed in the final battle with Thanos.

Then

> at the end when he goes back to the past, he has the Stones and Mjolnir.

But

> he returns as an old man with the iconic shield, which he gives to Falcon.

**So, where did *this* shield come from?**

Theories:

> 1. Stark made extras before he died.  2. Someone else made it or repaired it (Who?  Shuri?) 3. They got it from the past?

Comment: If it helps, the Russos confirmed in an interview that when he went back, Steve created a branched timeline where he lived with Peggy, and that he'd then had to travel back to the "prime" timeline in order to hand over the shield.  They don't explicitly say it but it's reasonable that he brought the shield from that alternate timeline.

Comment: @Dave:   Did he have it when he traveled back or not.   I seem to think he did, but now I'm doubting.

Comment: I don't remember seeing it, though he did have Mjolnir with him

Comment: No, he didn't take a shield with him when he went back. @Dave is correct. It seems to be one of those "not explained but from alt-timeline" things.

Comment: I don't think Stark made Steve Rogers a new shield in Endgame.  Rather, he gave him back the one he had kept ever since the end of Captain America: Civil War.  (with a new paint job, and the panther claw scratches smoothed out)

Comment: @NathanK.:   Didn't he say something like "I made you something." ?   I second thought, what you say makes more sense.

Comment: I think he said "My father made it for you."  Which was a neat follow-up to "That shield belonged to my father!" from the end of Civil War.

Comment: He says, "He made it for you".

Answer (score 10):

> He got it from the past.

There is an [interview](https://ew.com/movies/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-russo-brothers-captain-america/)  with the directors that explains Cap's ending, and

> when he was returning the stones he worked out a way to make it back to the main timeline and brought the shield with him.

Comment: Yes, a link to the interview, and an excerpt would make this answer more substantial.

Comment: Well, it's not that it would make it more substantial.   It's really quite essential to validating the answer.   Otherwise it's just an unsubstantiated claim.   I can't upvote or accept the answer without it.

Comment: Could you add the relevant quote from the interview into your answer so people don't have to go searching through the link to find it and in case the link dies.